# How do I compile a program in G++ on Ubuntu, having multiple source files?

Tags: c++, c, linux, unix

I have programme `main.cpp` that call other C++ programme `file1.cpp`, `file2.cpp` and `message.txt`

Please how can I write a command for compilation in Linux Ubuntu using g++, the main is not "void" it is written this way:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream.h>
#include "file1.h"
#include "file2.h"

int main( int argc, const char* argv[] ) 
{
    if( (argc != 2) && (argc != 4) ) 
    { ...
```

Answer (score 6):

To build it:

```
g++ -Wall -Wextra -g file1.cpp file2.cpp main.cpp -o program
```

Other good flags to add to g++ are `-std=c++11` for C++ 11 support and `-O2 -DNDEBUG` for optimized release builds.

To run it:

```
./program
```

Also, you should try to learn about make files. A makefile is a script run by `make` and it saves a recipe for building programs. Once your program gets more than a couple of source files, a makefile is a good idea.

Then, past makefiles are tools like autotools or CMake, which make makefiles for you.